# Convert date and time format in passed date value from db

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a date value from the database and its format is: `YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`
I want to convert it to this format: `YYYY/mm/dd hh:mm`

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $datetime = $value['last_online']; //from db
    $date = date('d-m-Y', $datetime);
    $time = date('Gi.s', $datetime);
    echo $date.' '.$time;
?>
```

But it's not working and is giving me an error of:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

I want to get rid of the minus signs and the seconds so my new date and time format would be `YYYY/mm/dd hh:mm`. How do I do it?

Any ideas?

Comment: $date = date('d-m-Y H:i', $datetime);

Comment: Thanks. But, still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below

```
$datetime = $value['last_online']; //from db
$date = date('Y/m/d h:i', strtotime($datetime));
```

Comment: Thanks. But, it doesn't do anything. It returns the same date & time.

Comment: What you really want to do?
In your question you said you want to change the format
S0 it gives the date in changed format

Comment: Sorry, I echoed the wrong variable. It's okay now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for marking it correct!